# How to return a function in Cython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython

I need to cythonize a function that takes in parameters lenscale and sigvar in order to construct a function.  I'd like to be able to do this without have to make k_se a class.  When I run the following code:

```
ctypedef float (*kfunc)(float, float)

cdef kfunc k_se(float lenscale, float sigvar):
    cdef float f(float xi, float xj):
        return sigvar**2. * _np.exp(-(1./(2. * lenscale**2.)) *\
                                    _npl.norm(xi - xj)**2)
    return f
```

I get the error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef kfunc k_se(float lenscale, float sigvar):
        cdef float f(float xi, float xj):
                                   ^
    ------------------------------------------------------------

BUILDGP.pyx:15:36: C function definition not allowed here
```

I've also tried this trying to return a lambda, which cython could not compile either.  Any ideas, do do I have to create a constructor class for k_se functions?

Comment: I think a cython class with a `__call__` method is the cleanest approach. I used this successfully and am not aware of any other solution.

Comment: Since functions aren't first class objects in C as they are in Python, it wouldn't surprise me if there was no way to write a Cython function that returned one (or a pointer to one after constructing it). Also seems like it would have to be able compile code on-the-fly...

Comment: A better title for your question would be "How to create and return a function in Cython?"

Answer (score 3):

You may construct a class, which can be initialized with a set of parameters and acts as callable:

```
class Function():
    def __init__(self, float lenscale):
        self.lenscale = lenscale

    def __call__(self, float xi):
        return self.lenscale*xi


f = Function(10)
print f(5)
```

[The cython documentation has more details on this.](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html)

Comment: this is not quite it - I'm looking for something that returns another function, which uses a a function I pass to it as an argument (specifically, it should take in an arbitrary distance metric).  The example here returns a float, not a function

Comment: Well, `f` is the function that is returned. I just call it afterwards to show that it's actually a function.

Comment: Ah I see.  Yeah, this answers what I wrote.  I forgot I wrote this and thought I had asked the more general question of passing a function as an arugment to another function.  For another time.  Thanks!